# sendgrid exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring-mvc, httpclient, sendgrid

I am getting exception when I try to use `SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(sendGridAPIKEY);` 
It gives exception because send grid uses `HttpClientBuilder.create().build();` internally.
I resolved this issue by adding following lines

```
DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
Client sendGridClient = new Client(defaultHttpClient, false);
SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(sendGridAPIKEY, sendGridClient);
```

where `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated.

But I want to know why `HttpClientBuilder.create().build()` line gives error.
I am using JDK 1.8 and following POM dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- send Grid dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception:

```
Nov 06, 2017 10:15:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V] with root cause
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:158)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:973)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
        at com.sendgrid.Client.<init>(Client.java:76)
        at com.sendgrid.Client.<init>(Client.java:56)
        at com.sendgrid.SendGrid.<init>(SendGrid.java:24)
```

Comment: If you using a deprecated Code, you must use the deprecated library version also. Theres no guarantee that the method will be keep for future releases.

Comment: Thanks Marcos. 
I know we should not use deprecated library that's why I want to use 

`HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();`

but above lines give error ( java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPool.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V ).

Comment: Aer you sure you are using the last library artifact version? You are using different versions for each component